# 3D struct in .Net?

Tags: .net, height, width, structure, depth

I always prefer to use existing (.Net source originated) structures and enums, over self creating them. I want to have a structure to define a 3d size. For 2D, [SizeF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab924f6y.aspx) does the job. What about width, heigth **and depth**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what *kind* of app you're writing, but if you're using WPF then [`Size3D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.size3d.aspx) might be what you want:

> Data structure that describes the size of a three-dimensional object.

Admittedly it (oddly) has `X`, `Y` and `Z` properties rather than `Width`, `Height` and `Depth` - but at least the name has the right implication.

(There's also [`Vector3D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx) and [`Point3D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d.aspx) where you need those.)

Comment: Its a winforms application. System.Windows.Media is not in the default list of namespaces to reference. I would need to define a cubic shaped volume. I could abuse `Point3D` but its name would be misleading, as its no dimension, but a point. Maybe my assumption of using PresentationCore.dll in winforms is bad practise, is my own set limitation here. `Size3D` would fit best if I can use PresentationCore.dll.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: Yes, that's reasonable - although it would have been nice to have said that in the question. I don't know of any equivalent for WinForms. (The Point3D class is also in WPF, for points in 3D space.)

Comment: It appears you have a very high ranking, if you say its reasonable to use PresentationCore.dll, then it is! Thanks, I will go for `Size3D`.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: No, I didn't say that it was a good idea to use that within a WinForms app... I just said that nowhere in the question did you give that as a requirement. If you're not using WPF, I suggest you write your own struct - it's trivial, after all.

Comment: OK. Misinterpretation. How about using a C# BackEnd that can have a winforms or WPF C# front end? The WPF frontend could deal with Size3D, but the winforms isn't. Should I still create my own structure in this scenario? This is not the case, but I am just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: In that case I probably would create a frontend-neutral representation, yes.